# Database: define relational schema for dataset of JSON document

Tags: database

I need to define relation schema for the data of a JSON document and part of the dataset is as follows:

```
{
    "business_id":"WNy1uzcmm_UHmTyR--o5IA",
    "full_address":"960 W University Dr Tempe, AZ 85281",
    "hours":{
        "Monday":{
        "close":"00:00",
        "open":"11:00"
    },
    "Tuesday":{
        "close":"00:00",
        "open":"11:00"
    },
    "Friday":{
        "close":"02:00",
        "open":"11:00"
    },
    "Wednesday":{
        "close":"00:00",
        "open":"11:00"
    },
    "Thursday":{
        "close":"02:00",
        "open":"11:00"
    },
    "Sunday":{
        "close":"00:00",
        "open":"11:00"
    },
    "Saturday":{
        "close":"02:00",
        "open":"11:00"
    }
}
```

I don't know how to choose the attributes for the table of the relation schema. Should Monday, close, and open be the attributes of the table, just like the picture?

[here is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlixy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have three functional dependencies: the full address of a business, the opening time per business and day and the closing time per business and day.  We can combine the opening and closing times since they have the same determinant and cardinality - exactly one per business and day.

```
business_id -> full_address
business_id, day -> open, close
```

Or in more tabular form:

```
business_address (business_id PK, full_address)
business_hours (business_id PK, day PK, open, close)
```

I didn't indicate FK constraints but that doesn't mean they're not important.